# Scala work-around for methods with same type after erasure

Tags: scala, erasure

I figured out how to use a `TypeTag` to add a empty parameter list to an existing method and bypass the erasure error.  I'd like to understand how my hack works and if there is a better way to achieve the desired outcome.

I have the following `happyStuff` method:

```
object Happy {

  def happyStuff(s: String): String = {
    "happy " + s
  }

}
```

I'd like to change the method signature of `happyStuff` and deprecate the old method as follows.

```
object Happy {

  @deprecated("this is the old one")
  def happyStuff(s: String): String = {
    "happy " + s
  }

  def happyStuff()(s: String): String = {
    "happy " + s
  }

}
```

This code gives the following error message: "def happyStuff(s: String): String at line 6 and def happyStuff()(s: String): String at line 10 have same type after erasure".

This hack gets me the result I want:

```
object Happy {

  @deprecated("this is the old one")
  def happyStuff(s: String): String = {
    "happy " + s
  }

  def happyStuff[T: TypeTag](x: T)(s: String): String = {
    "happy " + s
  }

}
```

How does the `TypeTag` solve the erasure message?  Is there a better way to achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 3):

It was not the type tag but the additional parameter that you put there:

```
object Happy {

  @deprecated("this is the old one")
  def happyStuff(s: String): String = {
    "happy " + s
  }

  def happyStuff[T](x: T)(s: String): String = {
    "happy " + s
  }

}
```

also compiles. Thing is that the currying "disappears" on bytecode level so you end up with:

```
def happyStuff(s: String): String
```

being the same as

```
def happyStuff()(s: String): String
```

and

```
def happyStuff[T](x: T)(s: String): String
```

the same as

```
def happyStuff[T](x: T, s: String): String
```

You could do something like

```
sealed trait Deprecated
object Deprecated {
  implicit val d: Deprecated = new Deprecated {}
}

object Happy {


  @deprecated("this is the old one")
  def happyStuff(s: String)(implicit d: Deprecated): String = {
    "happy " + s
  }

  def happyStuff()(s: String): String = {
    "happy " + s
  }

}
```

This way, the same code would work for old implementation... though it would change the signature, so bytecode compatibility would be lost. Alternatively, you could came up with some other way of "versioning the code", but the simplest/best way would be to either changing name (as it does something else) or the signature.

Comment: I think that the new version's JVM signature is the same as the old one's was, so in this specific case bytecode compatibility isn't lost.

Comment: Oh, well, yes I missed that. Then it would be an issue only if he wanted to explicitly call deprecated version until manually updated to newer.